# How to send json data to webapi through angular $http.get

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

WebAPI Code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult PostData(ARParameter allParams)
        {
               //My Code
        }

  public class ARParameter 
        {
            public string action;
            public SomeRules rule;
        }

 public class SomeRules 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PassFail { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to call `PostData` method

My javascript code is

```
 addData=function ($scope) {
            var data=
            +'{'
            +'    "action":"post",'
            +'    "rule":"{}"'
            +'}';


            $http({
                url: urlContent + '/api/Rules',
                method: "POST",
                params: { allParams: data }
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.rules = response;
            });;
        }
```

How to construct json ?

Answer (score 0):

### Server side changes

- Set the `ActionName` attribute in your action.

  ```
  [ActionName("PostData")]
  [HttpPost]
  public IHttpActionResult PostData(ARParameter allParams)
  {
         //My Code
  }
  ```

### Client Side changes

- `Json` format look likes

`var data= {"action":"post","rule":{"ID":"1","Name":"Ramesh","PassFail":"Pass"}}`

- Your client side codes should look likes

  `$scope.addData = function () {
                      var data= {"action":"post","rule":{"ID":"1","Name":"Ramesh","PassFail":"Pass"}}
                      $http({
                          url: urlContent + '/api/Rules/PostData',
                          method: "POST",
                          data: data
                      }).success(function (response) {
                          $scope.rules = response;
                      });;
                  }`

Comment: ``allParams`` are coming out as null

Comment: ``allParams `` is still null :(

Answer (score 0):

Your API method PostData is of type POST,so call should be POST. Below is the way to construct json.

```
var data={"action":"post","rule":{"ID":"123","Name":"namehere","PassFail":"passfailhere"}}
```

Comment: `rule` is a object only, it's does not a `List`. So you don't need `[]` in the json.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh for quick pick.

Comment: But not only this problem, He had lots of problems. I hope my answer will help him. with your key code...